# Format a single line of text using JSON

Tags: sharepoint-online, calculated-column-formula, json

I have a single line of text column in a sharepoint online list that is being populated with a dynamic value added by a workflow (the value is a url + the current created item ID added to it). And as the url that is returned is quite long and is taking too much of space in the list, I would like to replace the returned and populated url in the column with a shorter text, let's say 'Link' that will still lead to the destination generated by the workflow. Was looking for a way to do that on the net, but no success so far. Your help will be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What worked for me is the solution given in this article, used a REST call in a workflow to make it work:

https://www.sharepointsiren.com/2015/01/sharepoint-designer-2013-rest-api-set.html

Answer (score 1):

You can set the column (rich text column) in your workflow , instead of adding the url , add a link html tag , check the below example 
replace `[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]` with your generated url.

```
<a href=[%Workflow Context:Current Item URL%]>Link</a>
```